# WPF TextBox stealing focus after neighboring CheckBox is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I've had an annoying issue with focus for controls on a ToolBar in WPF. My toolbar has a CheckBox and a TextBox control next to eachother. If you click and edit the text in the text box, then click the check box, the text box steals the focus back after clicking the check box, and the check box state is not changed when the user clicks on it.

I have similar issues with text boxes all over my application, but I believe this is the simplest case to explain, and I hope that the problem will be a common issue across all my text boxes.

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: Are you working with native controls? could you share the relevant XAML?

Comment: have you tried isolating the problem in a new project? You should have some code causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Hook up a handler to the checkbox's Click event (or even the PreviewMouseUp event), and set the event's Handled property to 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that?:

private void MyCheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCheckBox.Focus();
    }